# Output to text file (My code is finished here I just keep putting my writer in the wrong spot)

Tags: java, text, output, fileoutputstream, writer

I am having trouble trying to output to a text file. Yes this sounds very simple but I keep putting my writer in the wrong spot so I just took it out and I'm using a system.out.println instead and it works but it prints to the console instead of a text file. This program reads in a text file with patient records, finds a tag, gets the info inside the tags, and prints it out to a text file which I'm having a hard time doing. It's comma delimited and formatted already I just need to print all the collected data to a text file. Please advise:

```
    package patient.records;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Writer;

    public class NoTagsOnlyData {
    private static final String RECORD_START_TAG = "<record>";
    private static final String RECORD_END_TAG = "</record>";
    private static final String newFileName = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OnlyData\\"; //this is for my output folder location
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    File records = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Input.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(records))) {
        StringBuilder record = null;
        String text = null;
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (text.contains("<PATIENT_ID>") && text.contains("</PATIENT_ID>")) {
                String end = text.substring(text.indexOf("<PATIENT_ID>") + "<PATIENT_ID>".length()  , text.indexOf("</PATIENT_ID>"));
                text = end;
                System.out.print(text+ ",");
            }
            if (text.contains("<AGE>") && text.contains("</AGE>")) {
                String end = text.substring( text.indexOf("<AGE>") + "<AGE>".length() , text.indexOf("</AGE>"));
                text = end;
                System.out.println(text+ ",");
            }
            if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
                if (text.startsWith(RECORD_START_TAG)) {
                    record = new StringBuilder(128);
                    record.append(text);
                } else if (text.startsWith(RECORD_END_TAG)) {
                    record.append(text);
                }
                else {
                    record.append(text);
                }
            }
        }
      }
    catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

If anyone would like to see the input text file please let me know. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: for sake completeness, plz post up ur txt file content thank u

Comment: What seems to be a problem? When `record` is complete - use `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Your last `if` does not make much sense: both `else`s do exactly the same.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to process XML. This will break as soon as the start/end tags for a data item are not on the same line, which is perfectly valid in XML.

Comment: Jim - this code has been tested and proven to work as I have tried it myself and have output in my console with a few hundred records and does not break.

Comment: usar - I removed my name...

Comment: PM - I don't know where to put the writer at in my code as I've stated in the title.